# FPPopover won't pop up on button press, just NSLogs "FPPopoverController dealloc"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller, fppopover

I have the following code:

```
- (IBAction)textOptionsTapped:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    UIView *buttonView = [sender valueForKey:@"view"];

    FPPopoverController *popover = [[FPPopoverController alloc] init];
    popover.arrowDirection = FPPopoverArrowDirectionDown;
    [popover presentPopoverFromView:buttonView];
}
```

What exactly is causing my app to NSLog "FPPopoverController dealloc" every time I press the button?

Comment: You need to hold onto a reference to that popover controller.

Comment: In an instance variable?

Comment: Yup, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation that's working in production. Try this out. It may just be that you haven't set all the properties correctly.

// Instantiate popover

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
LoginViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];

if (self.popover) {
    [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
    self.popover = nil;
}

self.popover = [[FPPopoverController alloc] initWithViewController:viewController];
self.popover.contentSize = viewController.size;
self.popover.border = NO;
self.popover.arrowDirection = FPPopoverNoArrow;
self.popover.tint = FPPopoverRedTint;

[self.popover presentPopoverFromView:self.loginButton];
```

Let me know if that helps